# How can I reduce downloading time of a page lots of image, Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image

I have a page lots of image, Image loads via ajax request and taking too long. How can I improve page loading?

Comment: this is a useful resource http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lazy load  .

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/

[LazyLoading](http://css-tricks.com/examples/LazyLoading/)

JQuery plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

```
$(function() {          
    $("img:below-the-fold").lazyload({
        event : "sporty"
    });
});
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {$("img.lazy").trigger("sporty")}, 5000);
});
```

Comment: You need to add some more detail, I'm tempted to flag this as a [link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers)

Comment: and vote changed accordingly! :)